# Fluent Nhibernate Mapping Multiple Join

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, join, fluent

I am somewhat of an Nhibernate newbie and I have been researching but am unable to figure out how to accomplish what I want using an Nhibernate mapping.

I have the following tables for my objects

- Domains
- Companies
- Dealers

Domains can have many Companies and Companies can belong to many Domains. Companies have many Dealers but Dealers only belong to one Company. I would like a mapping for my Domains to generate a list of all the Dealers that belong to it, via the Companies.

I have a join table called CompanyDomains (with columns CompanyID and DomainID) that maintains a many-to-many relationship between Companies and Domains. This table is currently NOT mapped in my Nhibernate setup...I just join on it with a HasManyToMany in my Domain map. The Dealers table has a column with the CompanyID.

The results I want are easily attained with an SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM Dealers
JOIN Companies on Companies.ID = Dealers.CompanyID
JOIN CompanyDomains on Companies.ID = CompanyDomains.CompanyID
WHERE DomainID = 1
```

This gives me all Dealers assigned to the Domain.

My question is, I want a List of Dealers in my Domain Mapping for this. How do I map that with Nhibernate?

If I have overlooked this solution elsewhere, please point me in the right direction, otherwise I appreciate any help you can provide.

Thanks!
Erick

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to map a `Dealers` collection for a company with `HasMany` and add a convenience property to `Domain`:

```
public class Domain
{
    ...
    public virtual IList<Company> Companies { get; private set; }
    public IList<Dealer> Dealers 
    { 
        get { return Companies.SelectMany(x => x.Dealers).Distinct(); }
    }
}

public class Company
{
    ...
    public virtual IList<Domain> Domains { get; private set; }
    public virtual IList<Dealer> Dealers { get; private set; } 
}

public class Dealer
{
    ...
    public virtual Company Company { get; private set; }
}
```

As there is no immediate relationship between `Dealer` and `Domain` I don't think you can map it directly.

Comment: It is not clear to me how this answers my question. Would you be able to explain based on my situation?

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer / explanation. I was thinking the route you've described would be a reasonable way if it wasn't possible to map it. Do you know if it is possible to create a mapping based on raw SQL?

Comment: @erickh: The closest you can come to that is probably a named query as described here: http://www.sidesofmarch.com/index.php/archive/2009/02/11/executing-native-sql-using-nhibernate-named-queries/ but it requires a session. You would also start polluting your model with persistance concerns which is probably not such a good idea